# Hadoop & eclipse are on different machines

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a linux server which has configured hadoop of version 1.0.4 which is in pseudo distributed mode. Server has only command line so I can not run eclipse on it. So I have to run eclipse from different machine which has windows environment.

Now, Problem is that how I can run or debug my mapreduce code in this situation. Is there any another way which can help me to work with hadoop?

Thanks.. In advance..

Note: I want to separate out hadoop on different machine and development environment like IDEs on another machines.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin in eclipse can help you doing this.Just search "hadoop  eclipse",you can find the method.
Or export a jar file in eclipse,and use a command "hadoop -jar" to run it

Answer (score 0):

Use any X-Server supported SSH application (for e.g. MobaXterm) and run eclipse from Linux.